# Divisors and Greatest Common Divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

> Prove that for every integer $n$ is of the form $4t, 4t+1, 4t+2$ or $4t+3$
>   for some $t ∈ Z$.

How would one approach this problem? Would it be somewhat similar to induction when one would assume that P(1) is true and substitute accordingly for t then eventually assume P(k+1) is true?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This has nothing to do with greatest common divisors

Comment: It is just Euclidean division of $n$ by $4$ where the quotient is $t$ and the remainder $\in\{0,1,2,3\}$

Comment: Well it has nothing to do with 4.  For any positive integer m then every integer n has a unique representation as n = mt + k where t and k are integers and 0 $\le$ k < m.  You have to prove this.  This is so basic you were taught it in the second grade but it was probably given as a fact.

Comment: In grade school you were taught that if you divide an integer into another integer you would get a quotient and a remainder and the remainder would be zero or less than the divisor.  This is *nothing* more or less than that.  Of course, n grade school we never proved this.  But it's clear by that if we start: n = 4(0) + n; n= 4(1) + (n-4);... inductively we'll get n = 4(t) + (n-4t) with n-4t $\ge$ 0 but n-4(t+1) < 0$.  i.e. 0 $le$ n-4t < 4.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it like this: If you divide the number $4t+l$ by $4$, you get a remainder of $l$. So all you need to show that every integer, when divided by $4$, has a remainder of $0, 1, 2,$ or $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want induction:

Proposition:  For all $n$ such thatn $-4m < n < 4m$ for any positive $m$ then $n = 4t + k;$ $k = 0,1,2,3$ for some integer $t$.

Initial case: $m = 1$ and $-4 < n < 4$ then $n =  4(-1) + 1; 4(-1) + 2; 4(-1) + 3; 4(0) + 0; 4(0) + 1; 4(0) + 2; 4(0) + 3$.

Induction step:  Assume true for $m$.  Show true for $m+1$.

Pf:  If $-4m < n < 4m$ then the proposition is true.  If $4m \le n 4(m + 1)$ then $n = n -4$ and $-4m < n-4 < 4m$ so $n - 4 = 4t + k$ so $n = 4(t+1) + k$.

Similarly if $-4(m+1) < n \le -4m$ then $-4m < n + 4 < 4m$ and $n + 4 = 4t + k$ so $n = 4(t-1) + k$.

So proposition is true for all n that can be expressed as being between any -4m and 4m.  As all integers n; $-4(|n|+1) < n < 4(|n| + 1)$ it is true that all integers can be expressed as $4t + k; k = 0,1,2,3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \in \mathbb N$.

- Consider the set $A=\{n-4s:s \geq 0, n-4s \geq 0\}$. It is non empty because $n \in A$.
- Call $r$ the minimum element of $A$ (it must exist by [well ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle)).
- By definition $r=n-4q$ for some $q\geq0$.
- We must have $r<4$. Suppose by contradiction $r\geq 4$ i.e. $n-4q\geq4$, this implies $n-4(q+1)=n-4q-4\geq0$ so we have find $r'=n-4(q+1)<n-4q=r$ and clearly $r'\in A$. Contradiction.
- We conclude that $n=4q+r$, $0\leq r <4$